# Styling Specific Objects Within A Div CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to style all ul's within the div #navbar and all a's within the div #navbar, how would I do that? I know how to do it with classes but not with ID's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough:

```css
#navbar ul {
  /* ... */
}
#navbar a {
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Yeah thats what I'm doing...Must of messed up elsewhere